# Calling non-pure function in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, side-effects, pure-function

I have the following code (simplified):

```py
def send_issue(issue):
    message = bot.send_issue(issue)
    return message

def send_issues(issues):
    return [send_issue(issue) for issue in issues]
```

As you see, `send_issues` and `send_issue` are non-pure functions. Is this considered a good practice (and Pythonic) to call non-pure functions in list comprehensions? The reason I want to do this is that this is convenient. The reason against this is that when you see a list comprehension, you expect that this code just generates the list and nothing more, but that's not the case.

UPD:
I actually want to create and return the list contrary this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: I would go against, if you are not intending to create a list.

Comment: As long as you're actually using the generated list as a list (meaning you are using indices to retrieve items of the generated list to do further processing I don't have a problem with it. If you intend to iterate over the list only, consider making it a generator expression rather than a list comprehension. If you don't care about the items at all, then you should use a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this. I say go for it; the method names are simple and obvious, which means if I was looking at this code, I would know what it does quite easily.

Comment: It's not obvious from the code itself that `send_issue` is non-pure. Does it send a message *and* return the contents of the sent message?

Comment: @chepner, yes it sends a message and returns the sent message, as written in the code.

Answer (score 4):

The question here is - Do you really need to create the list?

If this is so it is okay but not the best design.
It is good practice for a function to do only one thing especially if it has a side effect like I/O.
In your case, the function is creating and sending a message.
To fix this you can create a function that is sending the message and a function which is generating the message.

It is better to write it as.

```
msgs = [bot.get_message(issue) for issue in issues]
for msg in msgs:
     bot.send(msg)
```

This is clearer and widens the use of API while keeping the side effect isolated.

If you don't want to create another function you can at least use `map` since it says - "map this function to every element".

```
map(lambda issue: bot.send_issue(issue), issues) # returns a list
```

Also, the function `send_issue` is not needed because it just wraps the `bot.send_issue`.
Adding such functions is only making the code noisy which is not a good practice.